# Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes while running jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-plugin

I am trying to run the jar file of my project. I am working on STS. a But every time i am trying to run my jar file its giving me exception like Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

```
my pom.xml is 
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- <execution> <id>copy-dependencies</id> <phase>prepare-package</phase> 
                        <goals> <goal>copy-dependencies</goal> </goals> <configuration> <outputDirectory> 
                        ${project.build.directory}/${environment}/dependencies ${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/ 
                        </outputDirectory> <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases> <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots> 
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer> <includeScope>runtime</includeScope> 
                        </configuration> </execution> -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- <configuration> <excludeScope>system</excludeScope> <excludes>META-INF/*.SF</excludes> 
                            <excludes>META-INF/*.DSA</excludes> <excludes>META-INF/*.RSA</excludes> <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds> 
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory> 
                            </configuration> -->
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <!-- Additional configuration. -->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/resources
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.emo.process.EmoBatchProcess</mainClass>
                            <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>EMOBatchProcess</finalName>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/LOCAL</outputDirectory>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>all</shadedClassifierName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: Anyone please help me for this